# which one is best for using as a primary key in db?varchar or number.

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key

In my project i am using mysql database. In that i had created the tables which have the fields (email,username,.....etc).

In this table i kept email as a primary key.
Is this method is good to way of using primary key or i have to create number as a primary key like user_id (auto increment).
Which one is correct way and gives good performance to connect with other table in same database.

Comment: imo, items like email are not very good as the main identifier (primary key) to identify an entity over the lifetime of the entity. Why? They can and do change. They can be used to lookup the primary key, which is often a unique number. This gets really useful if a history of changes is required to be kept. i.e. you need to know what the old primary key was for that entity.

Comment: Thanks Ryan Vincent,i will accept your points keeping email id as primary key may give some risks.I have one more doubt is varchar as primary key create any performance or memory consumption problems or not?.I am already got some points from this post,better you can also give some points whatever you know,it was useful to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the InnoDB engine, the size of the primary key (PK) is important.

The size of the field(s) in the PK will affect the size of any [secondary indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html), as it will be stored along with the columns of the index. Choosing the wrong data type will lead to bloated indexes and increased disk usage. It will also mean more of the [buffer pool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html) will be used per index

If you need to refer to the row in another table then that will mean further increased memory and disk usage as you will need to store the PK in more than one place. The email address is certainly an example that will waste space if used as PK, since a BIGINT would be 8 bytes vs a VARCHAR of a much larger size

Answer (score 1):

Varchar comparison is slower than int comparison. However, this does not matter if you simply retrieve a user from the database using the e-mail address. It does matter if you have complex queries with multiple joins.

If you store information about users in multiple tables, the foreign keys to the users table will be the e-mail address. That means that you store the e-mail address multiple times.

Comment: thanks,is there is any slow processing while using varchar comparison.